# Does this histogram approximate any known distribution?

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Here is the histogram of the data:

[image]

What could be a distribution density function for the data of the histogram?

Comment: Have you tried dragging the correct image file directly into the editing box?

Comment: @Semiclassical Thank you, this worked.

Comment: The most obvious suggestion would be a sum of normal distributions, one for each of the five peaks. But pinning down means and variances of five different Gaussians seems unpleasant without some kind of theoretical justification.